# Alternatives to @apollo/federation package

Tags: typescript, graphql, microservices, apollo, apollo-federation

We're working on typescript microservices with REST APIs. We consider to implement GraphQL on each microservice add an API Gateway on the top level, so it will be just a single API.
At the moment we're just learning about what's possible to do, we have no knowledge about GraphQL servers.

We read that schema stitching is deprecated, and we're more interested in schema federation.

Is there any alternatives Apollo federation ?

Does the type-graphql package offers the same functionnality ?

**EDIT 1**

We don't want a cloud solution, we're building our own servers

We're looking for a low-level API (prefered, not required)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you check [this](https://product.voxmedia.com/2020/11/2/21494865/to-federate-or-stitch-a-graphql-gateway-revisited).
While Schema Stitching fell into deprecation limbo for a few years, its new maintainers have brought it back in a big way, and it feels like it’s breaking new ground into a post-extends era of GraphQL gateway design.

Answer (score 0):

Hasura io may work for your team, instant GraphQL for all your data.